# Wrapping matrix using % operator Java

Tags: java

I am taking an "intro to Java" type course and am running into some difficulty with an assignment.  My first question was closed for being too broad so I'm going to narrow it down.  It involves an operation with multiplication of 2 matrices that is difficult to explain so I'll give an example (I guess the term for it is convolution).

Say I have 2 matrices

```
A = {{1, 2, 3, 4},                     B = {{0, -1, 0},
     {5, 6, 7, 8},                          {-1, 5,-1},
     {9, 2, 4, 1},                          {0, -1, 0}}
     {3, 5, 7, 4}};
```

From these two matrices I need to create a new matrix, call it C.  To determine what, for example, C[1][1] should be, we need to match the center of matrix B (5) with A[1][1] (6) and do something similar to (but not the same as) matrix multiplication.  B[0][0] corresponds to the spot 1 row up and 1 column to the left of A[1][1], B[0][1] corresponds to 1 row above A[1][1], etc.  Then we need to take the sum of the products.  This results in 
C[1][1] = 0 * 1 + (-1) * 2 + 0 * 3 + (-1) * 5 + 5 * 6 + (-1) * 7 + 0 * 9 + (-1) * 2 + 0 * 4 = 14.  I've written a code that seems to work for non edge cases.  With an edge case, this is supposed to "wrap around" matrix A (i.e. for an entry on the left most column of matrix A the first column of B would correspond to the right most column of matrix A while for an entry on the right most column of matrix A the right most column of matrix B would correspond to the first column of matrix A, same applies to rows).  I'm trying to write a series of "if" statements for edge cases but it's getting very complex very quickly.  One of the hints for the class is to use the % operator for edge cases, I'm guessing if I do that it will cut down on required "if" statements.  Problem is, I'm not sure how I can use the % operator.  I keep trying to follow logic for this but I'm missing something.  I would really appreciate any assistance I can get.  This code should be able to be used for any size A and B, though I believe for this assignment it's safe to assume B will be an odd size square matrix.

For reference, here is the code I have so far for non edge cases (in this case it only solves for targetMatrix[1][1]):

```
private static int[][] GLOBALMATRIX = {
        { 2, 3, 5, 6 },
        { 1, 4, 3, 2 },
        { 9, 5, 6, 4 },
        { 6, 9, 3, 7 }
};

public static int[][] multiplyMatrix(int[][] someMatrix) {
    int width = GLOBALMATRIX[0].length;
    int height = GLOBALMATRIX.length;
    int[][] targetMatrix = new int[height][width];
    int vertDist = someMatrix.length / 2;
    int horizDist = someMatrix[0].length / 2;

    for (int row = 1; row < 2; /* targetMatrix.length; */ row++)
        for (int col = 1; col < 2; /* targetMatrix[0].length; */ col++)
            for (int i = 0; i < someMatrix.length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < someMatrix[0].length; j++)
                    targetMatrix[row][col] += someMatrix[i][j] * GLOBALMATRIX[row + i
                                - vertDist][col + j - horizDist];
```

The someMatrix matrix I passed in is identical to matrix B for reference.  GLOBALMATRIX corresponds to matrix A in my example and targetMatrix corresponds to matrix C.

P.S. Since this is an "intro" class we're supposed to stick to the basics, primarily loops and/or if statements.  Thanks again in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The % operator is rather good at doing wraparounds.

Let's talk about days of the week. If today is a wednesday, then tomorrow (+1 day) it is thursday. And 6 days from now (+6 days), it is.. tuesday. 538 days ago, it was a thursday.

That's a simple to understand wrapping situation. We really just want a number between 0 (monday) and 6 (sunday), and 'wrap' from there:

```
int today = 2; // today is wednesday;
int tomorrow = today + 1; // okay....
int sixDaysHence = today + 6; // this is not so good; that's 8, we wanted 1.
int longAgo = today - 538; // this is -536; we wanted 3.
```

So let's introduce that % operator. The % operator will give you the remainder after division. We don't want 8, we want 1. Why? Because you want to get rid of 'excess multiples of 7'. Which is the same as: divide by 7, forget about the result entirely, but go with the remainder. 8/7 is.. who cares - the remainder is 1, that's what we want here:

```
int today = 2; // today is wednesday;
int tomorrow = (today + 1) % 7; // okay....
int sixDaysHence = (today + 6) % 7; // yay! This is now 1!
int longAgo = (today - 538) % 7; // Hmm.. this is -4.
```

so the one caveat with % is that it will also do the remainder thing in the negatives, which is not actually what we wanted. Fortunately, there is an easy fix - after the modulo (%) operation, the answer will be no lower than -7, and no higher than +6. So if it's negative, we can just.. add 7!

```
if (longAgo < 0) longAgo += 7;
// or in one go:
longAgo = ((((today - 538) % 7) + 7) % 7);
```

this `(x + v) % range` concept lets you build wraparound into the very operation.

Surely this is enough for you to get further with your homework.

Comment: Ok, after including this in the code I am in fact able to get this "wrap" without the use of any "if" statements.  Thank you, your help is much appreciated.